# How to integrate hawtio with my spring application(and ActiveMQ)

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, hawtio

I am thinking to integrate the nice hawtio as a plugin into my current spring application with relies on ActiveMQ for JMS messaging. I try to find any resource to integrate this nice tool with spring application programmatically but it seems Spring boot is a must. Is there any simple way to integrate hawtio into a simple JMS application?

Also hawtio is on Apache Lincese 2.0, so is it ok to integrate hawtio with commercial products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your app is on Maven build, the easiest way is to [use the Maven plugin](http://hawt.io/maven/) directly.

Comment: Thanks but how it works when deploy the application on app server?

Comment: If webapp then why not just start the app with the Jolokia agent and connect to it either via either: a) the chrome Hawt.io plugin, b) war provided by Hawt.io to drop as is in same app server. Option a) is easier and safer